# Where was the Thirsting Blade warlock invocation officially published?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, product-identification, eldritch-invocations

As title says, where was the Thirsting Blade warlock invocation published? Is it from an official 5e book?

I'm trying to make a Pact of the Blade Hexblade warlock with Thirsting Blade. My DM isn't sure if it is legal so I need to find the source to use it.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how things work around here. This isn't a bad first question, Oblivious Sage edited it for you to make it a bit clearer. If you disagree or want to add anything you can further [edit] the question. Thanks for participating and happy gaming!

Comment: If you are wondering about downvotes. One of the reasons for downvoting is "lack of research effort", though this is a perfectly valid question. Questions that can be easily answered with free online sources like the [SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=50) or Basic Rules may attract downvotes. Don't stress about it. Stick around, ask and even answer more questions and you'll get the hang of it.

Answer (score 9):

## The Thirsting Blade invocation is from the *Player's Handbook* (PHB).

The Thirsting Blade [eldritch invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) for warlocks appears in the list of invocations in the PHB, on p. 111:

> *Prerequisite: 5th level, Pact of the Blade feature*
>
> You can attack with your pact weapon twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

It also appears on [p. 50 of the SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=50).

Comment: @Rightful: Glad to help! For future reference there's only 2 places it could have appeared if it was published: the PHB/SRD, and Xanathar's Guide to Everything. (There have been a few others in UA that were never published.)